# Label and TextBox value on button click as alert

Tags: c#, jquery, webforms

I need little help.

On button click I need values from the labels and txtBox'es shown in form of alert on the screen.

It should look like this:

1. Label0(value)    txtBoxOpis0(value)
2. Label1(value)    txtBoxOpis1(value) ....

The table has many more filed's, I copy'ed in this example only two rows.

```
<table id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike" style="color:#333333;border-collapse:collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
        <tbody><tr style="color:White;background-color:#507CD1;font-weight:bold;">
            <th scope="col">Karakteristike</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">Opis</th>
        </tr><tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
            <td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Karakteristike_0" mycustomattr="foo" margin-left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">GRP Total_Thickness</span>



                    </td><td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_0" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">1</span>

                    </td><td>                      

                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvKarakteristike$ctl02$txtBoxOpis" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_txtBoxOpis_0" margin-left="100px" style="font-family:Georgia;height:28px;width:130px;" type="text">

                    </td>
        </tr><tr style="background-color:White;">
            <td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Karakteristike_1" mycustomattr="foo" margin-left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">GRP Wear Layer thickness</span>



                    </td><td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_1" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">2</span>


                    </td><td>


                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvKarakteristike$ctl03$txtBoxOpis" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_txtBoxOpis_1" margin-left="100px" style="font-family:Georgia;height:28px;width:130px;" type="text">

                    </td>
        </tr><tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
            <td>
```

Here's the button

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$btnButton" value="Save" onclick="return false;" id="MainContent_btnButton" autopostback="false" type="submit">
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: "return false;" won't show an alert, have you tried anything else?

Comment: Alert works. I managed to show only value of a label:
$('#MainContent_btnButton').click(function () {
                
                  alert($( "#MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_1").text());
              });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Do something like this

```
$('#MainContent_btnButton').click(function () {
    alert(
    'Label0('+
    $("#MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_1").text()+
    ')\n(txtBoxOpis0'+
    $("#MainContent_gvKarakteristike_txtBoxOpis_1").text()+
    ')'
    );
});
```